# Highlight rows depending on month

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Table]

I have a table and a input where a person is supposed to enter a month 1-12, and when submitting, the rows from that month should turn red. How do I get the month out of these dates to determine which month they are from? I am unsure how to continue.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Kuukausi" id="searchMonth"/>
            <button type="submit" id="searchbutton">
            <span>Etsi</span></button>
            </div>
            <table style="width: 100%" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Lintu</th>
                <th>Päivä</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Varis</td>
                <td>20.4.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Huuhkaja</td>
                <td>14.9.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Pääskynen</td>
                <td>24.4.2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peippo</td>
                <td>30.3.2018</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We cannot convert images to code.

Comment: **a person is supposed to enter a month 1-12** You mean the input value would be `1` or `2`, etc.?

Comment: yes, the input value would be between 1 and 12

Comment: In JavaScript, you can use split, eg `"24.4.2018".split(".")[1]` gives you `4`.  But tell us what you are starting with.  Can you control the HTML there?  If so I'd tend to use CSS eg. `<td class="month-4">24.4.2018</td>`

Answer (score 2):

- Use a `type="number"` input element
- No need to "Submit" buttons.
- Add an ID to `tbody`
- Use JS TableElement `rows` and TableRowElement `cells` objects
- Use the `"input"` event to trigger a `searchMonth()` function
- Loop your TBODY TR elements, find the `1`th index cell and split its content by `.` dots to retrieve the month string.
- Check if the splitted date month equals to the inputed one
- Use JS `Element.classList.toggle('className', boolean)` to toggle the CSS `.highlight` class

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector("#tableTbody");

const searchMonth = evt => {
  const monthValue = evt.target.value.trim();
  [...tbody.rows].forEach(row => {
    const month = row.cells[1].textContent.split('.')[1];
    row.classList.toggle('highlight', monthValue == month);
  })
};

document.querySelector("#searchMonth").addEventListener('input', searchMonth);
```

```css
.highlight td {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<label>Month: <input type="number" id="searchMonth" min=1 max=12></label>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableTbody">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>20.4.2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>14.9.2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>24.4.2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>30.3.2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My only negative about using the `input` event rather than a button is that if you type 1 on your way to typing 10, 11 or 12 it will highlight the January values first and then switch to the October/November/December values

Comment: @Nick you can always add a function debounce. Whenever I can build something without a "Save" or "Submit" button - happy me , happy users - But depends always on the use-case.

Comment: @Nick you could solve that with a debounce timer that basically waits till you stop typing/clicking for like half a second then fires the event.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan lol, beat me to it

Comment: Yes, you should combine with `debounce javascript` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly,** You can get month value by using `split` like `currentText.split(".")[1]`

**Secondly,** The input type of `searchMonth` should be `number` to allow number value only.

```js
$("#searchbutton").on("click", function(){
   var searchMonth = $("#searchMonth").val();
   
   $("table tr").each(function(){
      var currentText = $(this).find(":eq(1)").text();
      var currentMonth = currentText.split(".")[1];
      
      var background_color = searchMonth == parseInt(currentMonth) ? "#00ff78" : "";
        $(this).css("background-color", background_color);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="Kuukausi" id="searchMonth" value = "4"/>
<button type="submit" id="searchbutton">
            <span>Etsi</span></button>
            </div>
            <table style="width: 100%" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Lintu</th>
                <th>Päivä</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Varis</td>
                <td>20.4.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Huuhkaja</td>
                <td>14.9.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Pääskynen</td>
                <td>24.4.2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peippo</td>
                <td>30.3.2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peippo</td>
                <td>20.02.2018</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @lev https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can be improved by converting to int, otherwise you get the issue where it's `2020.02.16` and they enter `2` - or the other way as the source data here indicates it would be `16.2.2020` and they enter `02` it won't match.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. Please take a look at

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```js
// handle click and add class
$('#searchbutton').on("click", function() {
  $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
  var rows = $('#table').find('tr');
  var value = $('#searchMonth').val().trim();
  $.each(rows, function() {
    var dateCol = $(this).find('td').eq(1);
    if (dateCol.length > 0) {
      var date = dateCol.text();
      var month = (date.match(/\d{2}.(\d{1,2}).\d{4}/) || [])[1];
      if (month == value) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }
    }
  });

})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Kuukausi" id="searchMonth"/>
            <button type="submit" id="searchbutton">
            <span>Etsi</span></button>
            <table style="width: 100%" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Lintu</th>
                <th>Päivä</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Varis</td>
                <td>20.4.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Huuhkaja</td>
                <td>14.9.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Pääskynen</td>
                <td>24.4.2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peippo</td>
                <td>30.3.2018</td>
            </tr> 
            </table>
```